# Imagen MVC en PDF con Rotativa no se ve

Tags: html, c#, css, mvc, pdf

Bien, tengo una gran duda. Al realizar la inserción de una imagen en la creación de un `PDF`, que necesito que esté de fondo, la imagen no se ve a menos que agregue datos y al hacerlo se ve acortada. Todo esto sucede si la ubico dentro del `style` en el `background`, ejemplo demostrativo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el código:

```
<body background="~/images/azul.png">
```

Leí por el foro que hay que usar el `@Server.MapPath`, lo que logra que se vea la imagen completa pero el problema es que necesito que se vean los valores sobre la imagen y no debajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<img src="@Server.MapPath("~/images/azul.png")" />
```

¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo? No se mucho de `CSS` por lo que no estoy muy familiarizado con esto.
¿Alguna sugerencia? Ejemplos o lo que sea, serán bien recibidos.

Comment: Intenta con `height` y `width` en `100%`. Bro, creo que llevar unas clases de CSS, HTML, JavaScript y demás tecnologías te ayudaría a entender mejor el escenario, puedo guiarte en el proceso de aprendizaje, contáctame por Twitter o Telegram, tengo el mismo nombre de usuario

Comment: Gracias por la pronta respuesta, la verdad bro es que me encantaría aprender css pero necesitamos que esto salga a producción mañana y no hay tiempo para aprender css justo ahora @fredyfx

Comment: Vale, cuando gustes hermano, ahí me encuentras. Como consejo, recuerda ir preparado a donde vayas, o al menos con una idea sólida, porque de otro modo, la situación se complica. Buena suerte lml

Comment: Pues no me ha funcionado lo del height and width pero gracias ajaja @fredyfx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fue añadir la imagen desde un archivo **css**:

```
body {
  background-image: url("ubicacion del archivo");
}
```